# How I can get the peak memory on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, delphi, memory, delphi-xe2

In Windows I can get the Peak Memory usage by calling GetProcessMemoryInfo

```
function TProcess.Peek: Cardinal;
var
  PMC: PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS;
  PMCSize: Cardinal;
begin
  PMCSize := SizeOf(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS);
  GetMem(PMC, PMCSize);
  try
    PMC^.cb := PMCSize;
    if GetProcessMemoryInfo(FHandle, PMC, PMCSize) then
      Exit(PMC^.PeakWorkingSetSize)
    else
      Exit(0);
  finally
    FreeMem(PMC);
  end;
end;
```

What is the Mac OS equivalent to do this?

Comment: here's a sample script in Python that shows using command line utilities and capturing their output to gather this info.   You could use the same approach from Delphi/Pascal. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/is-there-a-mac-os-x-terminal-version-of-the-free-command-in-linux-systems

Comment: Incidentally the POSIX APIs for memory usage do not function on OS/X so there is no PORTABLE way to do this that will work on OS/X and all common Unix/Linux systems.  I'm sure there is an OS/X-only API, and C++ wrappers like ACE include this functionality. Maybe Embarcadero should add this to their RTL.

Comment: This might be useful: [CHUD tools](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8506/apple-chud-tools)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `/usr/bin/time -l <cmd>` like this:

```
/usr/bin/time -l sleep 3
        3.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
    552960  maximum resident set size                  <--- this one (in bytes)
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
       144  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
         0  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
         0  voluntary context switches
         2  involuntary context switches
```

Comment: I was actually interested in having this done programatically via Delphi.

Comment: Oh sorry, you maybe want this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getrusage.2.html

Comment: As a heads up, zsh users will need the absolute path to `time`, see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76639/getting-zsh-command-not-found-time-when-running-time-in-subshell

Comment: Are you sure this is expressed in bytes, not kilobytes? See `man time` and https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getrusage&apropos=0&sektion=2&format=html

Comment: @SimonWarta The man-page for `time` on my Mac, says that the `-l` switch causes the contents of the `usage` structure to be printed. The man-page for `getrusage` describes the `ru_maxrss` field as `the maximum resident set size utilized (in bytes)`. I tried creating a 1MB, a 10MB, a 100MB and a 1000MB file with `dd` and slurping the whole file into a Perl variable and measured the RAM used and it seems consistent to me with the RSS being in bytes.